# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' Python 3 download long file

Tags: python, python-3.x, blob

I am trying to download a file in BLOB format with Python 3, this file is very 'heavy' for a database. Someone can help me with my code:

```
fout = open('D:\files.zip','wb')
def readBLOB ():
   try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='(IP)',user='(user)', passwd='(password)', db='(Database)', port=PORT)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        sql_fetch_blob_query = "SELECT archivo FROM versiones_archivos order by id desc limit 1"
        cursor.execute (sql_fetch_blob_query)
        fout.write(cursor.fetchone()[0])
        fout.close()

    finally:
        if (conn.is_connected()):
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
readBLOB()
```

The error I get is the following

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Any expert in python that can help me solve or have some other alternative to my script I would really appreciate

Comment: What line is giving the error? Can you include the full stack trace?

Comment: @jordanm Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update-hermes.py", line 24, in <module>
    readBLOB()
  File "update-hermes.py", line 17, in readBLOB
    fout.write(cursor.fetchone()[0])
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `cursor.fetchone()[0]` is a string, but you opened your file as `'wb'` (Write *Binary*, or *Bytes*), so you can't write a string to it - only `bytes` (to be precise, "bytes-like objects", as the error message says).

You should encode the string to get bytes:

```
try:
   ...
   fout.write(cursor.fetchone()[0].encode())
finally:
   ...
   # don't forget to close the file even if there's an error
   fout.close()
```